# Mapping Grails Domain object to JDBC table/sequence

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am trying to map an existing oracle table to a new Grails Domain Object.  I also have an existing sequence.  When calling "run-app", I get an error:

```
Unsuccessful: create sequence hibernate_sequence
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

My goal is to use the existing sequence, and not create a new one. For the record, this is my first Grails/Groovy attempt.

My domain object looks like below. Table name is `Uicc_Inv_Detail`. PK is `UICC_INV_DETAIL_ID`.  Other columns are the same name as in Uicc Class.  Sequence name is `Uicc_Inv_Detail_Seq`.
I assume my whole "id generator" section is wrong.

```
class Uicc {
  String id
  String iccid
  String imsi

  static mapping = {
    version false
    table 'Uicc_Inv_Detail'
    id generator: 'sequence',column:'UICC_INV_DETAIL_ID',
            params:  [table: 'Uicc_Inv_Detail_Seq', column: 'nextval']

  }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
id generator:'native', params:[sequence:'Uicc_Inv_Detail_Seq']
```

Here's the docs: 
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator

Comment: This worked, thanks.  I just had to modify it to  `id column: 'uicc_inv_detail_id', generator:'native', params:[sequence:'Uicc_Inv_Detail_Seq']`